# Serving markdown from Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, server, markdown

I am running Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) and am trying to access .md files and view them formatted as Markdown files.

If I point my browser to a .md file currently I either get a blank page or unformatted text (depending on OS and browser). I've looked in a number of places to try to solve this:

http://leancrew.com/all-this/2010/08/markdown-handler-for-apache/

http://projects.skurfer.com/Example.mdown

http://blog.tonns.org/2012/10/enabling-markdown-on-your-apache.html

http://marc-abramowitz.com/archives/2012/02/13/markdown-apache-handler/

http://daringfireball.net/linked/2007/05/24/markdown-cgi

and https://github.com/chdemko/apache-pandoc which seemed to be the most promising since the last commit was only 8 months ago and everything in the README file seemed at least relevant. Does anyone out there know any way to do this?

Comment: Without any server side processing, your files will just be sent to the requesting browser (with content type *application/octet-stream*, I suppose), leaving the browser to handle the unknown content. You will need to choose & install one of the plugins you mentioned, then Apache will convert your md files to proper HTML.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in my description. None of those plugins work, I am posting in the hopes someone can point me to a plugin that does.

Comment: Ok. Well, at first glance https://daringfireball.net/linked/2007/05/24/markdown-cgi looks serious. I think I would try running it and then ask questions on concrete problems encountered. If all these plugins do not work, maybe there is a fundamental problem with your Apache installation...

Comment: At first glance the daringfireball work is over 8 years old, written for Apache 1.3 and contains many broken links. In my original post I expressed pandoc is much more recent work but I've been unable to make this work on my system. I'm looking for someone who has some experience with this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [apache-mod-markdown](https://github.com/hamano/apache-mod-markdown) for display md trees on an apache server.

For many Debian based distributions (it works fine for Ubuntu 14.04LTS), you should install :

```
sudo apt-get install libmarkdown2-dev
sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
```

For the module build, you may need this libs :

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

Then download and unzip the archive and build the module like this...

```
autoreconf -f -i
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/bin/apxs2 --with-discount=/usr
make
```

and copy it to the install directory, like this:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/misc/apache-mod-markdown/ 
sudo cp ./.libs/libmodmarkdown.so /opt/misc/apache-mod-markdown/mod_markdown.so
```

Then configure apache:

```
echo 'LoadModule markdown_module /opt/misc/apache-mod-markdown/mod_markdown.so' > /etc/apache2/mods-available/markdown.load
touch /etc/apache2/mods-available/mardown.conf
```

Enable the module in apache:

```
sudo a2enmod markdown
```

Here is an example for vhost configuration:

```
Alias /docs/ /home/web/docs/
<Directory /home/web/docs/>
    AddHandler markdown .md
    DirectoryIndex index.md
    Options +Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    MarkdownCss /docs/css/stylesheet.css
</Directory>
```

you can take a look of this [tutorial](http://sweetohm.net/blog/115.html) (in french) for further informations

Comment: Trying to configure but receiving the error: `checking for apxs tool... configure: error: You need to specify the apxs file using --with-apxs`. Tried searching for apxs but no luck finding it.

Comment: Have you installed the apache2-dev package ?

Comment: I've been able to install the packages but the server still isn't displaying markdown. I can see the formatted text flash quickly then reverts to a normal page.

Comment: Silly question: you restart apache?

Comment: What is the apache version ?

Comment: like this `/usr/sbin/apache2 -V` if you return errors so try this `source /etc/apache2/envvars` and display you're return here pls

Comment: Have restarted. Apache version 2.4.7. @J1v3 Errors too long to display so posted here: http://pastebin.com/raw/ziuTeMXL.

Comment: @Josh try to set a proper FQDN like this issue http://serverfault.com/questions/558283/apache2-config-variable-is-not-defined

Comment: `sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev` needs to be `sudo apt-get install apache2-dev` now (see [apache-mod-markdown instructions](https://github.com/hamano/apache-mod-markdown)).

Answer (score 0):

Markdown files may be displayed using an external filter if you are not particularly concerned about high-volume traffic (it's not particularly efficient).  To do this you need to install the mod_ext_filter mod to apache and configure appropriately:

Install the markdown to html converters of your choice
(e.g. pandoc, multimarkdown, etc.)

Enable the ext_filter mod:

```
sudo a2enmod ext_filter
```

Edit the config file:

```
#Define markdown to html filters
ExtFilterDefine md-pandoc-to-html mode=output intype=text/markdown outtype=text/html cmd="/usr/local/bin/pandoc"
ExtFilterDefine md-multimarkdown-to-html mode=output intype=text/markdown outtype=text/html cmd="/usr/local/bin/multimarkdown"

#Define the filter to use in the appropriate directories/locations:
<Location /tst-md>
    ...
    SetOutputFilter md-pandoc-to-html
</Location>
<Location /tst-md/pandoc>
    SetOutputFilter md-pandoc-to-html
</Location>
<Location /tst-md/multimarkdown>
    SetOutputFilter md-multimarkdown-to-html
</Location>
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo apache2ctl -k graceful
```

Note that you may have to reload any urls you have previously viewed due to cacheing.